# selectOneChoice in ADF

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am new to ADF and facing some issues: I have an `af:selectOneChoice` component in my page, which contains a list of data.

I want to get the selected value when an user selects one option from the list of `selectOnceChoice` component.

I have used request bean with a parameter and bind it in the value option in property inspector of the component, but it failed to give the selected value. How can i get the selected value from the `selectOneChoice` component?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ValueChangeListener` of `selectOnceChoice` component.  In `valueChangeListener` you can bind it to a bean class method and call API to get the new or old value for `selectOnceChoice` component:

```java
public void selectOnceChoiceValue(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent){
    if(valueChangeEvent != null) {
        Object newVal = valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
        Object oldVal = valueChangeEvent.getOldValue();
    }
}
<af:selectOneChoice id="soc1" simple="true" autoSubmit="true"
   valueChangeListener="#{ExtnEmailNotificationPFBean.recipientTypeValue}"
   label="#{''}"
   binding="#{ExtnEmailNotificationPFBean.recipientTypeValue}"
   partialTriggers="cl2"
   value="#{pageFlowScope.ZcxEaNotificationRecipientType}">
  <f:selectItems id="si4"
          value="#{pageFlowScope.ZcxEaRecipientsTypeValueList}"/>                  
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need to do with the value one option is the following methods in your backing bean

```
public void valueChanged(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    this.setValueToEL("#{bindings.Deptno.inputValue}", valueChangeEvent.getNewValue()); //Updates the model
    System.out.println("\n******** Selected Value: "+resolveExpression("#{bindings.Deptno.attributeValue}"));
    System.out.println("\n******** Display Value: "+resolveExpression("#{bindings.Deptno.selectedValue ne ' ' ? bindings.Deptno.selectedValue.attributeValues[1] : ''}"));
}

public Object resolveExpression(String el) {      
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory =  facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();        
    ValueExpression valueExp = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext,el,Object.class);
return valueExp.getValue(elContext);
}

public void setValueToEL(String el, Object val) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory =   facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ValueExpression exp = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, el, Object.class);
    exp.setValue(elContext, val);
}
```

and you JSP component should look like

```
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.Deptno.inputValue}" label="Select Department"
                            required="true" shortDesc="#{bindings.Deptno.hints.tooltip}"
                            id="soc1" autoSubmit="true">
          <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.Deptno.items}" id="si1"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

From http://blogs.oracle.com/adf/entry/getting_selected_value_from_selectonechoice

This will get you the displayed text in real time, if you're looking more for a connection to the view object backing the component you'll want to look at something like.

```
public void buttonPressed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    // Get the binding
    BindingContainer bindings =
    BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    // Get the sepecific list binding
    JUCtrlListBinding listBinding =
    (JUCtrlListBinding)bindings.get("DepartmentId");
    // Get the value which is currently selected
    Object selectedValue = listBinding.getSelectedValue();
    System.out.println(selectedValue);
}
```

From http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/getting_the_value_from_a_selec

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, your problem is that value, you have selected with `af:selectOneChoice` will be available at bean, only after submit. If thats the case, then you should either let user submit the form, or set `autoSubmit` property of component to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
<af:selectOneChoice id="sampleId" 
value="#{bindings.sampleAttribute.inputValue}"
label="#{bindings.sampleAttribute.label}"
valueChangeListener=#"{Bean.valueChangeListener}"
immediate="true" autoSubmit="true">
    <f:selectItems id="sampleAttributeValues"
    value="#{bindings.sampleAttribute.items}"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

and the bean would have :

```
public void valueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent)
{
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the autoSubmit property to "true" make sure to set the immediate to "true" as well. Otherwise, validation would be fired at the page level.